# Coat/Backpack Hook Options for Concrete Wall

Tags: hanging

I live in a rental, the wall I want to use for coat hooks/kids backpacks is concrete. Command Hooks have failed, both in terms of the adhesive, and the plastic breaking. I know I can dirll holes with hammer drill/masonry bit/tapcon, but it's a rental, and seems like overkill.

I found hardwall hangers online. Seem like command hooks but stronger? Would those suffice, or is my only real option the drilling option. Open to any alternatives, the simpler the better.

Comment: Are there any options on non-concrete walls to put the hooks, or is the whole place concrete? If it's all concrete, a Tapcon™ or sleeve anchor would be the likely best option. If you get a nice looking hook, you could use a sleeve anchor and a decent looking screw to hold it in place. Just plan on leaving it behind. If the landlord doesn't want to leave it up for the next tenant (or the next tenant determines it's too many hooks), someone can pull then down later.

Comment: A rental will usually want to have permission before drilling.  If lucky the landlord might do it for you.

Comment: Is it actual concrete, or concrete block?

Comment: not 100% sure. i think we're going to just drill one into a wood closer door in the end

Answer (score 1):

> *I know I can dirll holes with hammer drill/masonry bit/tapcon, but it's a rental, and seems like overkill.*

Unless it is abundantly clear in your lease, find out whether you can drill holes to install proper anchors of some sort. If you can, great - do that, it is the best overall solution. You can provide pictures and more specific details to get recommendations of exactly what type of anchors, etc.

If you can't drill holes then I recommend an old-fashioned standalone coat rack of some sort. Here is [one example from Amazon](https://amzn.to/3TIgf7t):

[image: Coat rack]

but there are plenty of other styles available.

Comment: They are fun when the heavy weight coats are on one side.

Comment: thanks! i think we're going to end up putting one on a closet door nearby, and just drill into the wood

Answer (score 0):

To avoid concrete drilling, contact cement is an option. The stuff has the shear strength of water when you heat it up, so a hair dryer and some patience can eventually remove whatever you've glued.